# Check if XElement with particular value exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

For example for the following XML

```
 <Tree>   

   <Order>
     <Phone>1254</Phone>
     <City>City1</City>
     <State>State</State>
   </Order>  

   <Order>
    <Phone>765</Phone>
    <City>City2</City>
    <State>State3</State>
   </Order>   

  </Tree>
```

I might want to find out whether the XElement "`Tree`" contains "`Order`" Node with the value "City2" in its "`City`" child-node.

The following code returns whether the XElement City is exist, but does not check its value, How can I update it so that it meets my request?

```
bool exists = Tree.Elements("Order").Elements("City").Any();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an `Any` overload which accepts a predicate, so you just need to use that:

```
bool exists = Tree.Elements("Order")
                  .Elements("City")
                  .Any(x => x.Value == "City2");
```

Alternatively, use `Where` before `Any`:

```
bool exists = Tree.Elements("Order")
                  .Elements("City")
                  .Where(x => x.Value == "City2")
                  .Any();
```

Basically, just remember that you've got the whole of LINQ to Objects available to you.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. What is the difference between the two code snippets?

Comment: @user3165438: The first is more compact and very slightly more efficient, but they're equivalent in terms of effect.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler with xpath

```
var xml=@"<Tree>      <Order>     <Phone>1254</Phone>         <State>State</State>   </Order>     <Order>    <Phone>765</Phone>    <City>City2</City>    <State>State3</State>   </Order>     </Tree>";

XElement root=XElement.Parse(xml); //XElement.Load(xmlfile);
var child=root.XPathSelectElements("//Order/City[text()='City2']");
```

please include

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```